# Two reducers in-line from air compressor to air tool?

Tags: pex, compressor, npt

Previous house owner run PEX pipe in the garage from a 60 gal air-compressor to multiple hose reels. One of them developed a leak and I had to cut through copper pipe to remove it - it was all hard-piped from PEX to a chunk of adapters and copper pipes and eventually to the 1/4 MNPT which goes into the hose real.

Would love to have just been able to "unhook" the old reel and put in another one but instead I have to re-build connection.

So I am contemplating adding a quick-connect coupler into the mix so it goes like:

- Air compressor -> (1/2 PEX pipe) -> (1/2 PEX to 3/8 male adapter) -> (3/8 female to 1/4 MNPT adapter) -> (1/4 FNPT to female quick connector) -> (male quick connector to 1/4 FNPT) -> hose leading to reel

The question I cannot answer is: should I expect some air-flow issues?

The air will go from a larger supply to the quick-connect, which reduces it, and then goes from there, back into a wider hose reel until it reaches the second quick-connect at the air-gun/tool.

Is this a problem?

Motivation for this is to enable me to just quick-disconnect the hose reel if I want, to work on it, move it, whatever it, without having to physically cut things.

Comment: A **Union** fitting will permit "disconnect without cut" while not having either the restriction or the leak potential of another quick-connect. Likely costs less, too. On the rare occasion that you need/want to move the reel, you take a couple of wrenches to it for less than a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having used quick-connect (Schrader) connections for over 40 yrs, both on tools and 'extension' (rubber-type) tubing, up to maybe 40', I haven't noticed any loss. I'm using 1/4" valves, 150psi and a 13cfm compressor. It may affect tools such as da sanders, but for everything else, i've had no issues. Best thing would be to give it a try - there's not much extra work involved if it isn't satisfactory for your situation.

Comment: Realized I have done this before to extend a tube for stapler and it was fine for stapling. Odd I did not make that connection... Would not affect pressure though right? I.E. my 1/2 inch impact suddenly losing nut removal torque? Loss of cfm is not a concern, not sand blasting/spraying

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to hook up something high flow like a sandblaster you need to consider higher flow fittings like 1/2pex to 1/2MNPT -> 1/2FNPT to 1/2in universal/Chicago hose coupler -> 1/2in coupler to hose reel whip

Comment: True, could just use more beefy couplers